# UIWebView content loads successfully but gives pop up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am loading (1) HTML string (2) Web URL in `UiWebView`. For some content, I am getting alert: "There is some issue while processing your request" still it loads content.

The following delegate called:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Is there any issue related to web content or is there something from iOS side? My App deployment target is iOS 10, so I can not use `WKWebView`.

Comment: WKWebView - ios 8+. Try loading hello world html file first if that gives you popup.

Comment: Actually issue was this: `loadHTMLString:` was being called twice at first launch and that is why it was giving error callback for second call. Error callback was containing that error message.